# Print two lines of stars with WConio.gotoxy() at different locations in console

Tags: python-3.x

```
import WConio

i=0
WConio.gotoxy(0,0)
while i<80:
    print("*",end="")
    i+=1
i=0
WConio.gotoxy(0,20)
while i<80:
    print("*",end="")
    i+=1
print("")
input()
```

It prints only one line at x == 20 and exits.

Comment: Hi! Welcome on StackExchange.
You should start by reading the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help). For good questions guidelines, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You never set `i` back down to zero. This causes the second loop's condition to be false immediately, so the loop is never executed. Add `i = 0` before the second while loop.

Comment: adding i=0 after first loops prints two lines consecutively at x=20, i want to create a border for snake game

Comment: This does indeed "print two lines of stars"; what have you tried in order to get the vertical lines?